# Firestore charging for document snapshot in Riverpod provider

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I have setup a riverpod provider in order to listen to a document in firestore as shown below.

My assumption was that the document is only read once after the start of the app and then only read / charged when the content has changed.

When I run the firestore emulator it shows me frequent GET calls against this object.

Is there a way to stream a single object without document reads or do I have to use a query snapshot for that?

```
final habitProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<ObjectRepository, AsyncValue<Object>>(
        (ref) => ObjectRepository(ref.read));

class ObjectRepository extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<Object>> {
  final Reader _reader;
  StreamSubscription<Object>? _subscription;

  ObjectRepository(this._reader) : super(AsyncData(Object.empty())) {
    state = const AsyncLoading();
    try {
      _subscription?.cancel();
      _subscription = getObject().listen((event) {
        state = AsyncData(event);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      state = AsyncError(e);
    }
  }

  Stream<HabitCollection> getObject() {
    final docReference =
        _reader(firebaseFirestoreProvider).collection("x").doc("y");
    final snapshot = docReference.snapshots();
    return snapshot.map((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.data() == null) {
        return Object.empty();
      } else {
        return Object.fromJson(
            snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
      }
    });
  }

  void dispose() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```